# prometheus notis "sample timestamp out of order"

Tags: docker, monitor, prometheus

This is my `prometheus.yml` config info:

```
$ cat /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml 
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

rule_files:
  - "/etc/prometheus/alert.rules"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    metrics_path: "/metrics"

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.30.30.6:9090']
        labels:
          group: 'monitor'

  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.30.30.5:8080', '172.30.30.6:8080', '172.30.30.11:8080']
        labels:
          group: 'monitor'

  - job_name: 'node-exporter'
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.30.30.5:9100', '172.30.30.6:9100', '172.30.30.11:9100']
        labels:
          group: 'monitor'

  - job_name: 'alertmanager'
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['172.30.30.6:9093']
        labels:
          group: 'monitor'
```

In the Prometheus ui, all target states are up.In the graph of the UI, no datapoints found.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWH0b.png)

Here is the information for the Prometheus log.

```
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape health sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=up{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.11:8080", job="cadvisor"} => 1 @[1492947990.969] source="scrape.go:586" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape duration sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.11:8080", job="cadvisor"} => 0.122665982 @[1492947990.969] source="scrape.go:589" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape sample count sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.11:8080", job="cadvisor"} => 0.122665982 @[1492947990.969] source="scrape.go:592" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape sample count post-relabeling sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.11:8080", job="cadvisor"} => 0.122665982 @[1492947990.969] source="scrape.go:595" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Error on ingesting out-of-order samples" numDropped=1332 source="scrape.go:533" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape health sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=up{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.5:9100", job="node-exporter"} => 1 @[1492947991.37] source="scrape.go:586" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape duration sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.5:9100", job="node-exporter"} => 0.067132553 @[1492947991.37] source="scrape.go:589" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape sample count sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.5:9100", job="node-exporter"} => 0.067132553 @[1492947991.37] source="scrape.go:592" 
Apr 23 19:46:31 localhost prometheus[31806]: time="2017-04-23T11:46:31Z" level=warning msg="Scrape sample count post-relabeling sample discarded" error="sample timestamp out of order" sample=scrape_duration_seconds{group="monitor", instance="172.30.30.5:9100", job="node-exporter"} => 0.067132553 @[1492947991.37] source="scrape.go:595"
```